# Select rows from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried a lot of the solutions to this problem in other similar questions, but I can't make it work.

I have a table in my database called 'game' with the columns: k1, k1r, k2, k2r, k3, k3r and week. The week-column is automatically inserted with the week of the year and the others are user-inputs from a betting game I made.

Then I have a table called 'matches' with the columns: match1, match2, match3, week. Again, same procedure with the week-column. The other 3 I fill out with the matches we should bet on.

I then have a query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM game 
WHERE week = '.$week;
```

`$week` is already set as `$week = Date('W');`

It outputs a table, where I write the matches in 3 columns and then echoes the users bets in the rows under the matches. But instead of me changing the php-script every time there are new matches, I would like it to take them from the table 'matches'. In that way, I also keep the old matches in the database.

So, now to my question :)

What I would like to do is something like:

```
'SELECT * FROM game WHERE week = '.$week.' JOIN * FROM matches WHERE week = '.$week;
```

but as you probably now, that won't work :/

But what should I do then?

Comment: you should have like a foregin key in the matches table that links the two tables together. For example, when you save a game also save the matches as well, e.g id_match_fk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Query should be like this. 
You basically link matches with game using the week. You can also link using the id of matches which is better and more unique. But try this below

```
  select g.*,m.* FROM game g inner join matches m on g.week=m.week where g.week='.$week;
```

Comment: Your answar is correct too.. But I think I made a mistake in my question. I need it to loop through the 'game' table and take all rows, but I only need one row, one time from the 'matches' table. When I do it like what you say, it echoes the match-row in between every 'game'-row?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, then try this:

```
SELECT * FROM game g JOIN matches m ON g.week = m.week WHERE g.week = ' . $week;
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!! Can you explain to me the `ON` part? Because I have som other conditions I just didn't write now :)

Comment: @DanielJensen more information in reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

By simple, that "on" using for set binding between columns at other tables for joining its

Comment: But I also need it to select the rows from 'game' where the column 'grp' is bs. So actually before the join, it was `'SELECT * FROM game WHERE week = '.$week.' AND grp = 'bs''` .. How can I write that?